# Docker containers stop after starting them

Tags: docker, warden

I'm using Warden with Magento, and I notice that when I start a project with "warden env up", all containers boot up, but immediately some of them stop working (the image shows in gray the ones that turned off).
[image]
Here los logs:
[image]
[image]
Additionally, when I try to connect to view the database using the MariaDB container, I get this message stating that my IP is not allowed to connect.
Have you experienced this error before?
[image]

Here connection to mariadb inside container:
docker exec -it b4abe54d7042 mariadb --user=root
[image]

Comment: If you have logs, we can provide you with more accurate answers. For MariaDB, can you connect to db inside the container ?

Comment: Thanks, I've posted a screenshot of the logs and I have successfully connected to MariaDB inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

Without logs, it is difficult to tell but here are the main problems encountered.

For elasticsearch, it is most probably a problem with map count. If you check your logs you must have something regarding max_map_count.

You can set it at system level so you don't have problem each time you restart your machine.

```
sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=524248
```

For rabbitMQ, it is most probably ports that are not available.